# Add hardcoded string with function return values in flask route to display the hardcoded string with the return values when the api is called

Tags: python, json, string, flask, routes

I want to add a hardcoded string with function return values in flask route to display the hardcoded string with the return values when the api is called. I will be passing a filelink in my api call which will be downloaded and then processed to return the values as displayed in my code. The function which returns the set of values is

```
    def convert(fname, pages=None,encoding='utf-8'):
        if not pages:
            pagenums = set()
        else:
            pagenums = set(pages)

        output = StringIO()
        manager = PDFResourceManager()
        converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

        infile = open(fname, 'rb')
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
        infile.close()
        converter.close()
        text = output.getvalue()
        if len(text)>=500:
            regex3=re.search(r"\d*(?:[.-]\w+)*\s*(General Information|Process validation|Justification of Specification(s)|Manufacturer(s)|Batch Formula|Description of Manufacturing Process and Process Controls|Controls of Critical Steps and Intermediates|Post Approval Stability Protocol and Stability Commitment)",text,re.IGNORECASE)
            if regex3:
                org = []
                with open('C:\\Users\\msk\\.spyder-py3\\organizations.csv', newline='', encoding ='latin1') as myFile:
                    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
                    for row in reader:
                        if len(row[1])>=4:
                            v = re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(row[1]) + r'\b', text, re.IGNORECASE)
                            if v: 
                                a = v.group(0)
                                org.append(a)
                                break
                dosage = []
                with open('C:\\Users\\msk\\.spyder-py3\\dosage.csv', newline='', encoding ='latin1') as myFile:
                    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
                    for row in reader:
                        if len(row[1])>=4:
                            w = re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(row[1]) + r'\b', text, re.IGNORECASE)
                            if w: 
                                b = w.group(0)
                                dosage.append(b)
                                break
                substances = [] 
                with open('C:\\Users\\msk\\.spyder-py3\\substances.csv', newline='', encoding ='latin1') as myFile:
                    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
                    for row in reader:
                        if len(row[1])>=4:
                            z = re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(row[1]) + r'\b', text, re.IGNORECASE)
                            if z: 
                                c=z.group(0)
                                substances.append(c)
                                break                            
                o = 'Folder:'+ regex3.group(1), 'Organization:'+ "".join(org), 'Dosage:'+ "".join(dosage), 'Substances:'+ "".join(substances)

                o = list(o)
                str_list = ",".join(o)
                #str_list = eval(str_list)
                str_list = str_list.replace("'", "")
                #print(str_list)
                #str_list = str_list.strip('"\'')
                return str_list
           else:
               pass
```

The api code is:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<string:path>')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def download_file(path):
    x= request.url.rstrip('?')
    x=x.replace(' ','%20')
    print(x)
    y = x[22:]
    #y = r"http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
    #print(x)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(y)
    #response=requests.get(x,proxies=proxies)
    #print(response.status_code)
    file = open('D:/mahai_.pdf', 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    categories = convert('D:/mahai_.pdf')
    return categories


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run the following code passing a file link to the api, my expected output is for example:

```
Folder:MANUFACTURERS,Organization:test,Dosage:,Substances:Polyethylene
```

But the output I am seeing in the browser is:

```
MANUFACTURERS,test,,Polyethylene
```

How do I make my function return the hardcoded strings along with the values. Other way to do this will be to jsonify the output but I don't know how to do it so help is soughted.

Comment: Your convert function should work fine assuming the data is correct, so I would assume the problem is with the data itself. What is the original data you are downloading in the api?

Comment: It's a downloadable pdf link, so when I click on the link it downloads automatically. I am passing that link to my `def download_file(path):` function where the path argument is nothing but the file link. Then the convert function processes the saved pdf and returns the values